# How to get TRC20 transactions to an address

Tags: blockchain, tron, tronweb

I am using tron web to query transactions of an address but it does not return transactions sent to that address where token transferred is TRC20.

This does not work.
I want to get the transactions on an address and get both TRX, trc10 and trc20 transactions.

What am I doing wrong or how to do that?

Here is my code block:

```
  tronWeb.setDefaultBlock("latest");
  var result = await tronGrid.account.getTransactions(address, {
    only_confirmed: true,
    only_to: true,
    limit: 10
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
})();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found out one can easily query contract events at intervals to get transactions on that contract address and you can then filter it for the address you are watching since you can't get a webhook or websocket with your trongrid/tronweb implementation.

Here is a sample file I used to achieve this and it works great for monitoring many address even with different contract addresses.

Note: In my own implementation, this node file is called from another file and other logistics are handled in the other file, but below you see how I queried the transfer events emitted by the specified contract

```
const TronWeb = require("tronweb");
const TronGrid = require("trongrid");

const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
  fullHost: "https://api.trongrid.io"
});
const tronGrid = new TronGrid(tronWeb);
const argv = require("minimist")(process.argv.slice(2));
var contractAddress = argv.address;
var min_timestamp = Number(argv.last_timestamp) + 1; //this is stored for the last time i ran the query
(async function() {
  tronWeb.setDefaultBlock("latest");
  tronWeb.setAddress("ANY TRON ADDRESS"); // maybe being the one making the query not necessarily the addresses for which you need the transactions

  var result = await tronGrid.contract.getEvents(contractAddress, {
    only_confirmed: true,
    event_name: "Transfer",
    limit: 100,
    min_timestamp: min_timestamp,
    order_by: "timestamp,asc"
  });
  result.data = result.data.map(tx => {
    tx.result.to_address = tronWeb.address.fromHex(tx.result.to); // this makes it easy for me to check the address at the other end
    return tx;
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
})();
```

You are free to customize the config data passed to the `tronGrid.contract.getEvents` method. Depending on how frequently transactions come on the contract you are monitoring you should DYOR to know at what interval is great for you and what limit value you should pass.

Refer to https://developers.tron.network/docs/trongridjs for details.

Comment: Is there a way to get all transfer events for TRC20 (example USDT), not only for one particular user (Address)?

Comment: This is exactly what this answer explains. The `tronGrid.contract.getEvents(contractAddress, {...})` fetches the events.

Answer (score 0):

I found a API that can take TRC20 transactions, but I haven't found an implementation in webtron.

```
https://api.shasta.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/address/transactions
```

Related document:
https://developers.tron.network/reference#transaction-information-by-account-address

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = require('request');
var contract = "TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t"; //usdt
var wallet = "TQiC7LJUtnagUcwzcc6ULRmXiHipf4Tbou"; //publicKey
var url = "https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/" + wallet + "/transactions/trc20?limit=100&contract_address=" + contract;
request({
    headers: {
        "TRON-PRO-API-KEY": '63d4cba8-xxx-ab8d4c91834e'
    },
    uri: url,
    method: 'GET'
}, function (err, res, body) {
        var transcol = JSON.parse(body).data;//list of last 100 wallet usdt transactions
        var sentArray = transcol.filter(function (el) {
            return el.to == wallet
        });//list of last recived usdt transactions in to wallet

        var lastReciveValue = (parseInt(sentArray[0].value) / 1000000);
        var lastReciveTransid = sentArray[0].transaction_id;

        console.log('last transaction: ' + lastReciveValue + ' USDT');
        console.log("https://tronscan.org/#/transaction/" + lastReciveTransid);
});
```

- **transcol** : list of latest 100 *usdt* transactions that related to the **wallet**
- **sentArray** : list of latest **recived** *usdt* transactions in to the **wallet**
- **limit=100** : you can remove this to get all related transactions to the **wallet**, or change it to custom value.
- **contract_address=** : you can remove it to get transactions in all type of currencies.
- **lastReciveValue** : the last usdt value that sent to the **wallet**
- **lastReciveTransid** : the last transaction id that sent usdt to the **wallet**.

**sample of return json object:**

```
"transaction_id":"b02049daa9a0de0e10187dfa4d1ce560c3e8dd23625e92d2adfcf242e1af5891",
"token_info":{
"symbol":"USDT",
"address":"TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t",
"decimals":6,
"name":"Tether USD"
},
"block_timestamp":1689029211000,
"from":"TQiC7LJUtnagUcwzcc6ULRmXiHipf4Tbou",
"to":"TAiZ8qT2ggJDCRf6xutDKSnEjiCnFDm22K",
"type":"Transfer",
"value":"5000000"
}
```