# Im trying to fetch all transactions of a certain tron address

Tags: blockchain, tron, tronweb, tronlink

i couldnt find a way to get the history of transactions a certain Tron address is involved in

i tried the tronweb API : https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/TJmmqjb1DK9TTZbQXzRQ2AuA94z4gKAPFh/transactions/trc20?limit=100&contract_address=TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t

yet this didnt do anything.
so has anyone managed to find a way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quiet simple just make a `GET` request to the following url:

```
https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/{wallet-address}/transactions/{standard}?&contract_address={contract-address}
```

Replace `{wallet-address}` with your desired tron wallet address.

Replace `{standard}` with the standard of token that you want e.g. `trc20`.

Replace `{contract_address}` with the address of the contract of your target token e.g. `TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t` (USD Tether).

Here are all possible parameters :

- **only_confirmed** (boolean) :
  *true | false. If false, it returns both confirmed and unconfirmed transactions. If no param is specified, it returns both confirmed and unconfirmed transactions. Cannot be used at the same time with only_unconfirmed param.*
- **only_unconfirmed** (boolean) :
  *true | false. If false, it returns both confirmed and unconfirmed transactions. If no param is specified, it returns both confirmed and unconfirmed transactions. Cannot be used at the same time with only_confirmed param.*
- **limit** (int32) :
  *number of transactions per page, default 20, max 200*
- **fingerprint** (string) :
  *fingerprint of the last transaction returned by the previous page; when using it, the other parameters and filters should remain the same*
- **order_by** (string) :
  *block_timestamp,asc | block_timestamp,desc (default)*
- **min_timestamp** (date-time) :
  *minimum block_timestamp, default 0*
- **max_timestamp** (date-time) :
  *maximum block_timestamp, default now*
- **contract_address** (string) :
  *contract address in base58 or hex*
- **only_to** (boolean) :
  *true | false. If true, only transactions to this address, default: false*
- **only_from** (boolean)
  *true | false. If true, only transactions from this address, default: false*

Comment: i had a success hitting this endpoint, but what remains are trx and trc10 transactions, if i replace the standard with trx or trc10 it returns an error while it works for trc20, any idea as to why?

Answer (score 2):

I had success by hitting this endpoint: ([docs here](https://developers.tron.network/reference/events-by-contract-address))

```
https://api.trongrid.io/v1/contracts/${contractAddress}/events?block_number=${blockNumber}&only_confirmed=true
```

It looks like another option is to use TronWeb's `getEvents()` endpoint:

[How to get TRC20 transactions to an address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940476/how-to-get-trc20-transactions-to-an-address)

There is also this, which seems kind of similar:

https://developers.tron.network/reference/geteventresult

Comment: well this seems to give the history of transactions of a contract address, yet what i want is the history of transactions of a wallet address

Answer (score 1):

The tron GET endpoint you're looking for is: `"api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/{address}/transactions"`

Replace `{address}` with your tron wallet address. Cheers!

Comment: Here's a link to the Tron dApps developer guide: https://developers.tron.network/docs/exchangewallet-integrate-with-the-tron-network#trongrid-api-endpoint

Comment: Note that this returns only few token transactions. To make sure you get them all you need to call also api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/{address}/transactions/trc20

Answer (score -1):

You can download it in a CSV format from the tronscan.org

but keep in mind that only the first 10,000 transactions are available.
[image]