# How to get a list of all transactions of USDT TRC20

Tags: node.js, tronweb

How can I get a list of all transactions in the USDT token Tron network using TronWeb. I found a solution but it doesn't work for me.
[How to get TRC20 transactions to an address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940476/how-to-get-trc20-transactions-to-an-address)
My code:

```
let result = await tronGrid.contract.getEvents(contractAddress, {
            only_confirmed: true,
            event_name: "Transfer",
            limit: 100,
            min_timestamp: 1662961248,
            order_by: "timestamp,asc"
        });
        result.data = result.data.map(tx => {
            tx.result.to_address = tronWeb.address.fromHex(tx.result.to);
            return tx;
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

The console is empty, no error or response.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76772698/11239018